# Order in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I would just like to ask about a problem that I have with my query/queries. For example I have the following result from a query which is a union of 4 queries:

```
alpha,alpha,alpha,bravo,bravo,bravo,charlie,charlie,charlie,delta,delta,delta
```

what do I need to do to have the order of the result to:

alpha, bravo, charlie, delta, alpha, bravo, charlie, delta, alpha, bravo, charlie, delta?

I apologize if this question might have already been answered before here in stackoverflow as I don't know the proper keywords for this problem for me to search the database. Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: First of all, why are you expecting duplicates in your results? And secondly, why can't you do the necessary reordering in the code that calls this?

Comment: You'll need some secondary column to sort by. What is the table schema?

Comment: query sample will be usefull.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Basically, I just used the phonetic codes to represent the different types of posts that we've declared on a website we're constructing. I just want them to have an even distribution to minimize the cluttering together of posts with other posts with the same type. Mahmoud Gamal's answer seems to be a temporary solution to our problem right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a new column something like a sortorder:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT acolumn, 1 AS sortorder FROM table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT acolumn, 2              FROM table2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT acolumn, 3              FROM table3
   UNION ALL
   SELECT acolumn, 4              FROM table4
) u
ORDER BY aColumn, sortorder;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the distinct keyword:

```
Select DISTINCT
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can either order numerically `(1>2>n)` or alphabetically `(a>b>x)`. How data is ordered depends on the type to order.

Mahmouds answer is creating a numerical field you can order the union by.